# Issues with the Numbering of a Bible Verse Index

Tags: indexing, bibleref

I've been trying to create a Bible verse index for a Bible project, and I currently have some problems with the numbering of the books in the index.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{bibleref}
\usepackage{indextools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\otest{\textbf{\large Old Testament}}
\def\ntest{\textbf{\large New Testament}}
\biblerefmap{Genesis}{1@\otest!01}
\biblerefmap{Exodus}{1@\otest!02}
\biblerefmap{Leviticus}{1@\otest!03}
......
\biblerefmap{ISamuel}{1@\otest!09}
\biblerefmap{IISamuel}{1@\otest!10}
......
\biblerefmap{Zechariah}{1@\otest!38}
\biblerefmap{Malachi}{1@\otest!39}
\biblerefmap{Matthew}{2@\ntest!01}
\biblerefmap{Mark}{2@\ntest!02}
......
\biblerefmap{ICorinthians}{2@\ntest!07}
\biblerefmap{IICorinthians}{2@\ntest!08}
......
\biblerefmap{Jude}{2@\ntest!26}
\biblerefmap{Revelations}{2@\ntest!27} %% I numbered all the books of the Bible in the same manner. 
\makeindex[title=Scripture Index,name=scr,options=-s MyStyle.ist, intoc]
\renewcommand{\biblerefindex}{\index[scr]}
\begin{document}
......
\printindex[scr]
\end{document}
```

And here's MyStyle.ist:

```
delim_0 "\\dotfill\ "
delim_1 "\\dotfill\ "
delim_2 "\\dotfill\ "
```

Here's the final product: [image]

[image]

As can be seen from the pictures, the books whose names begin with a number (such as 1 Samuel, 1 Corinthians, etc.) are placed at the very end of the index list in alphabetical order with respect to the first character after the number. Moreover, the book of 1 Samuel has also been placed with the books of the NT even though I have defined it to be part of the OT. So my question is then if there is a way to have all the books in the order as they appear in the Bible grouped based on OT and NT.

I'm also open to any suggestions to how I can improve the way the books are cited.